# Tinymce theme modification renderHTML

Tags: tinymce

I'm creating a theme for TinyMCE, and need to change how the buttons are rendered on the editor.

I can do this by modifying some of the code in the main **tiny_mce.js** file in the renderHTML method:

```
    renderHTML : function() {
        var cp = this.classPrefix, s = this.settings, h, l;

        l = DOM.encode(s.label || '');
        h = '<a role="button" id="' + this.id + '" href="javascript:;" class="' + cp + ' ' + cp + 'Enabled ' + s['class'] + (l ? ' ' + cp + 'Labeled' : '') +'" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" aria-labelledby="' + this.id + '_voice" title="' + DOM.encode(s.title) + '">';
        if (s.image && !(this.editor  &&this.editor.forcedHighContrastMode) )
            h += '<img class="mceIcon" src="' + s.image + '" alt="' + DOM.encode(s.title) + '" />' + l;
        else
            h += '<span class="mceIcon ' + s['class'] + '"></span>' + (l ? '<span class="' + cp + 'Label">' + l + '</span>' : '');

        h += '<span class="mceVoiceLabel mceIconOnly" style="display: none;" id="' + this.id + '_voice">' + s.title + '</span>'; 
        h += '</a>';
        return h;
    },
```

but, I need to have this done just for the specific theme I'm creating.  Is there a way not to touch the main tiny_mce.js source file, but rather to modify renderHTML method behavior in the **editor_template.js** file for the theme?  I just haven't been able to find a way to do this.